# First fundamental form

Tags: differential-geometry

I am looking at the following exercise of the book of A.Pressley:

Let $$Edu^2+2F dudv+Gdv^2$$ be the first fundamental form of a surface
patch $\sigma(u, v)$ of a surface $S$.

Show that, if $p$ is a point in the image of $\sigma$ and $v, w \in T_pS$, then
$$\langle v, w \rangle = E d u (\textbf{v})d u (\textbf{w}) + F(du(\textbf{v})dv(\textbf{w}) + du(\textbf{w})dv(\textbf{v})) + Gdv(\textbf{w})dv(\textbf{w})$$

$$$$

Can you give an idea?

I don't really have a clue what to do.

Comment: how do you understand $du^2, dudv$ and $dv^2$?

Comment: and how do you understand $T_p S$, what is a vector $v \in T_p S$?

Comment: $T_pS$ is the tangent space and a vector $v\in T_pS$ is a tangent vector. Correct? @LeVanTu

Comment: The First fundamental form is a dot product. Correct? @janmarqz $du$ and $dv$ are linear maps. Or not?

Comment: the point of view in A.Pressley is a little difference from the one I known in Do Carmo. And I think the Do Carmo "Differential geometry of Curves and Surface" would give you more information to understand the notion "first fundamental form".

Comment: At which point is there a difference? At the definition of $du^2$, $du \cdot dv$ and $dv^2$ ? @LeVanTu

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you understand that the $du$ and $dv$ are linear functionals, then you must realise that the symbolisms $du^2$, $dudv$ and $dv^2$ are abbreviations for three bilinear maps $T_pS\times T_pS\to\Bbb R$ which are defined as soon as one understand that there is a basis for $T_pS$. 
And in fact, they should be written as $du\otimes du$, $du\otimes dv$ and 
$dv\otimes dv$.

But the basis for $T_pS$ is $\frac{\partial}{\partial u}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial v}$ where let us briefly rename as 
$\partial_u=\frac{\partial}{\partial u}$ and 
$\partial_v=\frac{\partial}{\partial v}$.

So, 
because $du(\partial_u)=1$, $du(\partial_v)=0$, $dv(\partial_v=0$ and 
$dv(\partial_v)=1$.
Then 
$$du^2(\partial_u,\partial_u)=du(\partial_u)du(\partial_u)=1$$
$$du^2(\partial_u,\partial_v)=du(\partial_u)du(\partial_v)=0$$
$$du^2(\partial_v,\partial_u)=du(\partial_v)du(\partial_u)=0$$
$$du^2(\partial_v,\partial_v)=du(\partial_v)du(\partial_v)=0$$

Similar for $dudv$ and $dv^2$.

Now, if you are compelled to have a inner product in $T_pS$ then, the natural way to pair a couple of tangent vectors $X,Y$, one must consider them as a linear combinations 
$$X=X^u\partial_u+X^v\partial_v,$$
$$Y=Y^u\partial_u+Y^v\partial_v,$$
and one can define first the metric coefficients
$E=\langle \partial_u,\partial_u\rangle$,
$F=\langle \partial_u,\partial_v\rangle$ and
$G=\langle \partial_v,\partial_v\rangle$.

Hence 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\langle X,Y\rangle&=&(Edu^2+2Fdudv+Gdv^2)(X,Y)\\
&=&Edu^2(X,Y)+2Fdudv(X,Y)+Gdv^2(X,Y)\\
&=&EX^uY^u+2FX^uY^v+GX^vY^v\\
\end{eqnarray*}
gives us a scalar product in $T_pS$.